# Extracting data from xml tags not on the same line

Tags: xml, sed, xmllint

I have a xml and want to extract the data between the two tags. The tags are not on the same line. I tried the sed command below, but that returns the whole entire XML. what am I doing wrong? I have also tried xmllint and get the same results.

```
sed 's/<.tagname*>\(.*\)<\/.tagname*>/\1/g' file

xmllint --path '//anytag/text()' <(echo "<anytag>my message</anytag>"
```

Comment: use an XML parser instead, like xmllint or xmlstarlet

Comment: I tried xmllint   ```xmllint --xpath '//anytag/text()' <(echo "<anytag>my message</anytag>")``` but i get a "xpath set is empty"

Comment: I tried xmlstarlet `xml sel -t -v '//anytag' <<<'<anytag>my message</anytag>'` and I got `my message`.

Comment: I changed from --xpath --path and that works except that it now returns the entire xml.

Comment: Some call it [summoning the daemon](https://www.metafilter.com/86689/), others refer to it as [the Call for Cthulhu](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) and few just [turned mad and met the Pony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8344060). In short, never parse XML or HTML with a regex! Did you try an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint` or `xsltproc`?